# Assigning Resolved Issues to Reporter Except If Reporter Is Not In QA Group

Tags: jira, user-management, jira-plugin

I am currently revising our JIRA workflow and issue routing and have the following predicament.

I want to *assign* all *resolved* issues back to the original reporter *EXCEPT* when the reporter is not in the *QA Group*. Then the issue should be assigned to a single user instead (in this case our QA Lead).

Having researched several plugins and threads I have yet to find anything similar or anything that would help achieve that.

If you require more information, please let me know. Your help, as always, is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Jira Version 5.2

Answer (score 0):

We wrote a similar custom plugin for a customer:

"This post function can be added to a transition such as Resolve
where a developer is indicating that the issue is ready for
testing. The aim is to reduce QA manager triage work.

If the reporter is a member of a configured group such as QA:
    Then change the assignee to the reporter
Else change the assignee to the configured lead of the QA group"

Please email info@customware.net if this sounds relevant.

~Matt

Comment: Indeed it does, you should have my email in your inbox as we speak.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by *"wish to assign all resolved issues"*?

If you mean you want to go over all issues and do this then you better you can use the [REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+APIs), for example use [jira-python](http://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)  to write a script that will go trough all issues and make the changes.

**If you want to apply this rule to all issue being resolved**- this can be done quite easily using [Jira's scripting suite](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.quisapps.jira.jss) or [Jira Groovy Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner) (depends on your jira version) to attach a post function to the `resolve issue transition` in the workflow that will check each issue and make the needed changes.

If you need help with coding any of those solutions or more information let me know..

**Update**

Using [Jira Groovy Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner), add a [script post function](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/GRV/Script+Runner#ScriptRunner-Conditions,Validators,PostFunctions) to the `resolve` transition to your workflow. the script should be something like:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager
import com.atlassian.jira.user.util.UserManager
import com.atlassian.jira.security.groups.GroupManager
import com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.User

MutableIssue myIssue = issue
User reporter= issue.getReporter()
GroupManager usersGroup = (GroupManager) ComponentManager.getComponentInstanceOfType(GroupManager.class);
Collection<String> currentUserGroups = usersGroup.getGroupNamesForUser(reporter)
if ('QA' in currentUserGroups) {
  // assign issues back to the original reporter 
  issue.setAssignee(reporter)
} else {
  // EXCEPT when the reporter is not in the QA Group
  // Then the issue should be assigned to the QA Lead.
  issue.setAssignee(ComponentManager.instance.userUtil.getUserObject('qa_leader_name'))
}
```

for more information check out [Jira's API](http://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/).

Comment: I am not looking for a batch operation. I want (workflow-wise) that when any issue is set to resolved to go back to the original reporter unless said reporter is not in the QA group. In which case it should go to a single user (QA lead).

Comment: Hi Kuf, it's for JIRA 5.2, also added the version to the original question.

Comment: I just gave it a try, but I am getting the following error: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property

Comment: Thanks for the update Kuf. Unfortunately I am still getting an error: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: issue for class: Script6 I made sure to change the QA Lead's name as well as the QA groups name in the script. Any suggestions? Thanks again for all your help. Some additional info, I get this error after pasting it into the script field for Groovy/Script Runner. I have the Groovy Script Engine selected.

Comment: That's weird.. I've tested it myself on Jira 5.2 and it worked. Just to make sure, did you install the [Script runner plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner)? which version? did you add the script as a post function to the resolve transition of the desired workflow? this is the only error? no other details? I'm trying to understand where did the `MissingPropertyException` exception came from.